# multy window from Lua

Tags: java, android, lua, luajava

```
public static ActivityOptions getActivityOptions(Context context) {
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
    int freeform_stackId = 5;
    try {
        Method method = ActivityOptions.class.getMethod("setLaunchWindowingMode", int.class);
        method.invoke(options, freeform_stackId);
    } catch (Exception e) { /* Gracefully fail */
        }

    return options;
}
```

How to implement this code in LuaJava??

This is the code I'm trying to implement::

```
    pm = activity:getPackageManager()

    Intent = pm:getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")

    Intent:addFlags(bit32.bor(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK))

    u = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&travelmode=driving&origin=50.291793,30.355700&destination=50.400024,30.623489"
    Uri = luajava.bindClass("android.net.Uri")

    Intent:setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    Intent:setData(Uri:parse(u))

    ActivityOptions = luajava.bindClass("android.app.ActivityOptions")
    options = ActivityOptions:makeBasic()
    freeform_stackId = 5
    method = ActivityOptions.class.getMethod("setLaunchWindowingMode", 366712642) --int.class)
    method:invoke(options, freeform_stackId)

    --bundle = {left=50, right=50, top=200, bottom=200}
bundle = luajava.newInstance("android.graphics.Rect",50,50,200,200)
    mOptions = Options:setLaunchBounds(bundle)

    startActivity(Intent, mOptions.toBundle())
```

This is an example of Lua code that should display the google map in a window with a given size.
The problem is in this fragment(I guess):

```
Method method = ActivityOptions.class.getMethod("setLaunchWindowingMode", int.class);
```

How to implement it?
I generally had a question: Does this tool work without manual intervention...programmatically???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).